# PC weird sound issue

Tags: cpu, gpu, fan, noise

Specs:

- A SSD & HDD
- Gtx 1660
- i7 6700
- DDR4 ram
- Windows 10 pro
- Corsair TX650M  650W PSU (maybe a year old)
- Gigabyte B450M DS3H ( maybe a year old too)

The issue I have is that my computer sounds like an old HDD. It's not the GPU because even though It's unplugged, I can still hear the noise. It sounds like it's from the motherboard/CPU.

What's weird is when I change my power options from High performance to Energy Saver - The noise is reduced by a LOT and I can barely hear the noise.

Here's a video i recorded so you can hear the noise I'm talking about - https://streamable.com/xyawek

What I've tried:

Changing from High performance -> Energy saver (partly fixed the issue but reducing WoW fps with like 40fps)

- Replaced ram
- Removed GPU
- Removed CPU to place back in

Kindly, please help me :-)

Comment: Sounds like you probably have a worn bearing in a fan, try running the fans on their own from the power supply.

Comment: @spikey_richie thank you for your support. It's just weird to me because that noise sounds "mechanical". But I'll check if i can figure out how to run the fans from power supply..

Comment: If changing the energy mode changes the sound then it can be the PSU (or it's fan) as well as the CPU power regulators that are located on the Mainboard next to the CPU. In any way using the high power energy plan is IMHO a bad plan that should not be used. It should be called "power waster". Usually the best mode is "adaptive".

Comment: @Robert Thank you. The issue is that when I have the mode on Balanced, I still here the noise. And I dont want it on energy saver because It's reducing my FPS a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details info about your Mainboard, PSU and the other components plus their age. If the sound is new it may be just the indicator that you mobo is dying.